# How to Set id for each row of a column

Tags: javascript, html, select

This is one of the rows in my table.

```
<td>
   <select id="itemcodeid" name="itemcode[]" class="form-control itemcode">
      <option></option>
      @foreach($productsdata as $d)
            <option>{{$d->itemcode}}</option>
      @endforeach
      </select>
</td>
```

I am using Select2 to fill data.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $("#itemcodeid").select2
       ({
            placeholder: "Select Itemcode",
            allowClear: true
        });
</script>
```

But when i add rows to table how to refer the upcoming rows with id. Because this works only on first row.

Below is image of first row.
[image]
[image]
But in Other rows i am unable to type and select(second image) because id reference is not done so kindly tell how to refer id of the rows added.
Help or suggestion will be highly useful.Thank You.

This is the code which gets executed when i press the plus button(verify image).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.addrow').on('click',function()
  {  addrowfn();
  });
  function addrowfn()
  {
    var tr =  '<tr>'+
              '<td>'+
              '<select id="itemcodeid" name="itemcode[]" class="form-control itemcode">'+
              '<option></option>'+
              '@foreach($productsdata as $d)'+
              '<option>{{$d->itemcode}}</option>'+
              '@endforeach'+
              '</select>'+
              '</td>'+
              '<td><input type="text" name="proname[]" class="form-control proname"></td>'+
              '<td><input type="text" name="actualprice[]" class="form-control actualprice"></td>'+
              '<td><input type="text" name="discount[]" class="form-control discount"></td>'+
              '<td><input type="text" name="gst[]" class="form-control gst"></td>'+
              '<td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="form-control quantity"></td>'+
              '<td><input type="text" name="finalprorate[]" class="form-control finalprorate"></td>'+
              '<td><input type="text" name="finalbillrate[]" class="form-control finalbillrate"></td>'+
              '<td>'+
              '<a href="#" class="remove btn btn-danger">'+
              '<center>'+
              '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>'+
              '</center>'+
              '</a>'+
              '</td>'+
              '</tr>';
    $('tbody').append(tr);          
  }
  $('body').on('click','.remove',function()
    {  var l=$('tbody tr').length;
       console.log(l);
    if(l==1)
    {  alert('You Cannot Remove all Rows!!!');
    }
    else 
       $(this).parent().parent().remove();

  });
</script>
```

Kindly Tell me if there are any corrections.

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: can you show me the loop that create `<td>` ?

Comment: yes, i am adding it.

Comment: Are you using php code `foreach`? If yes I think the code will not show the result that you showed in the picture.

Comment: Yes,I am retrieving data for select.But It is the output obtained.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this code works, as I haven't tested it, but I would, at minimum, make these two changes:

1. Listen for the appended node using a *MutationObserver*, then turn
   the regular select into a select2();
2. Create a variable to keep track of the rows, and make each select's ID dynamic, e.g. 'itemcodeid_3' and 'itemcodeid_5' etc. Do the same for 'name' attribute

   ```
   var target = document.getElementById('<INSERT_ID_HERE>'); 
   var rows = 1;
   if (target) {
       var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
           mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
               if (mutation && mutation.addedNodes) {
                   mutation.addedNodes.forEach(function(el) {
                       if (el && el.nodeName === "SELECT") {
                           $(el).select2();
                       }
                   });
               }
           });
       }); 

       observer.observe(target, {
           childList: true
       });
   } // end if

   $('.addrow').on('click',function()
   {  
       addrowfn();
   });
   function addrowfn()
   {
       rows++;
       var tr =  '<tr>'+
                 '<td>'+
                 '<select id="itemcodeid_" ' + rows + ' name="itemcode_' + rows + '[]" class="form-control itemcode">'+
                 '<option></option>'+
                 '@foreach($productsdata as $d)'+
                 '<option>{{$d->itemcode}}</option>'+
                 '@endforeach'+
                 '</select>'+
                 '</td>'+
                 '<td><input type="text" name="proname[]" class="form-control proname"></td>'+
                 '<td><input type="text" name="actualprice[]" class="form-control actualprice"></td>'+
                 '<td><input type="text" name="discount[]" class="form-control discount"></td>'+
                 '<td><input type="text" name="gst[]" class="form-control gst"></td>'+
                 '<td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="form-control quantity"></td>'+
                 '<td><input type="text" name="finalprorate[]" class="form-control finalprorate"></td>'+
                 '<td><input type="text" name="finalbillrate[]" class="form-control finalbillrate"></td>'+
                 '<td>'+
                 '<a href="#" class="remove btn btn-danger">'+
                 '<center>'+
                 '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>'+
                 '</center>'+
                 '</a>'+
                 '</td>'+
                 '</tr>';
       $('tbody').append(tr);          
   }
   $('body').on('click','.remove',function()
   {  
       var l=$('tbody tr').length;
       console.log(l);
       if(l==1)
       {  
           alert('You Cannot Remove all Rows!!!');
       }
       else {
          $(this).parent().parent().remove();
       }

   });
   ```

It may not work because it sees the appended node as  instead of ...have to test

Additionally, you may wish to look at using a template engine for this, such as [John Resig's jQuery solution](https://johnresig.com/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) or [Mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js),
 [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/)